# Etymology of "Soundacious"

Tags: etymology, adjectives, slang

I found this definition of 'Soundacious' in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=4952106&term=Soundacious):

> 1. Musically brilliant
> 2. Aesthetically pleasing to the ear
>
> *The most soundacious band is playing inside; you’ve gotta hear them.*
>
> *Thunderstorms are soundacious.*

What is the etymology of the word?

A quick search in Cambridge, Oxford, and MacMillan didn't yield any results.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Comment: Yup. But no luck. :(

Comment: You need to indicate what research you have done in your question. Maybe you spelt *soundacious* wrong?

Comment: Sorry. Indicated my research and spelling seems correct.

Comment: This is really simple; it's _sound_ just with a fun sounding ending.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - yes probably on the model of other slang terms ending in -acious. Can you think of any?

Comment: I can only think of salacious and tenacious but no slang terms.

Comment: +fywe But there are two different spellings of the word in your question

Comment: It is fairly common to see a nonce word created by appending *-acious* to another word.  A very small number of such nonce words make it into the informal idiom.

Comment: There's lots of 'made-up' stuff in UD that just hasn't caught on by anybody else (someone just felt like having fun). So at this point an etymology is just speculative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because urban dictionary isn't a suitable reference for purporting a word exists, hence rendering asking for its etymology pointless.

Answer (score 2):

More than a few nouns that end in *-acity*, *-ace*, or *-acy* have adjective forms that end in *-acious*. For example: *audacious*, *capacious*, *efficacious*, *gracious*, *mendacious*, *perspicacious*, *pugnacious*, *spacious*, *tenacious*, and *veracious*.

But I agree with Mick (in a comment beneath J O S H 's answer) that the probable source word is *bodacious*. Here is the entry for that word in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **bodacious** *adj*. {prob. blend of *bold* and *audacious*} **1** *Southern & Midland [U.S.]* **:** OUTRIGHT, UNMISTAKABLE **2 :** REMARKABLE, NOTEWORTHY {a *bodacious* bargain} **3 :** SEXY, VOLUPTUOUS {*bodacious* babes}

The crucial sense that emerges from all of these meanings is one of excellence or desirability, and it follows that *soundacious* probably attaches the excellent/desirable element of *bodacious* to the sound of the thing being so described.

As a slang term, *soundacious* is as yet so young that it seems not to have appeared in any published dictionary of slang. I would expect that situation to change in the next few years, however, if it retains (and perhaps increases) its popularity for a while longer.

Answer (score 0):

There is really very little information on the slang term ***[soundacious](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=4952106&term=Soundacious)*** though it appears to be commonly used in [social  networks](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=soundacious). Only the UD entry suggests it's been used at least from 2010. There is no evidence on Google Books and  this suggests that the term was probably coined around that year.

The origin is clearly from "sound" +***["acious"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-acious)*** in an original attempt to create  a new adjective from the noun "sound", probably on the assonance with terms like "tenacious" or "audacious".

Dictionary.com

Comment: There is also [*bodacious*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bodacious).

Comment: @Mick - good one!

Comment: I must say (+1 to Mick) that as soon as I read 'soundacious' I thought of 'bodacious'.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this word. It was the name of my independent record company back in 1996 or so, and there was no sign of its use anywhere else on the nascent web or internet then, as far as I can tell.

Back in 2011, I used the word as part of the title for my folk music podcast That's Soundacious, and [episode 1](http://thatssoundacious.podomatic.com/entry/2011-06-12T20_35_43-07_00) includes my best definition.

> The word "soundacious" is my own invention, and it's been the name of my record label for 15 years. It's a mashup between the words "sound" and "delicious" ... or maybe "audacious" ... or "spacious" ... or "courageous". I never really bothered to come up with a definition for it. But for the sake of this podcast, something is "soundacious" if it excites me and moves me and I feel the need to let more people know about it.